# Programa en C que funciona pero aparece "Violación de segmento (`core' generado)"

Tags: c

Tengo una consulta un poco extraña. Hice un programa que me lee dos archivos y me genera otro. Uno de los archivos es una lista con nombres de la siguiente manera:

```
nombre1

nombre2

nombre3
```

etc
y el otro archivo tiene el siguiente formato:

```
nombre1 texto

texto

nombre2 texto

texto

nombre3 texto

texto

etc
```

Este  ultimo es muy largo.
El programa en cuestión es este:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

FILE *infile1, *infile2, *infile3;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

int i, j;
char name_dom_lista[10], name_dom[10], len_sec[25], sec_dom[1000];

infile1=fopen(argv[1], "r");
infile2=fopen(argv[2], "r");
infile3=fopen(argv[3], "a");

for (j=0; j<49; j++) {
    fscanf (infile1, "%s", name_dom_lista);

    for (i=0; i<434857; i++){

    fscanf(infile2, "%s" "%s" "%s", name_dom, len_sec, sec_dom);
        if (strcmp(name_dom_lista, name_dom) == 0) {
            fprintf (infile3, "%s/" "%s\n" "%s\n", name_dom, len_sec, sec_dom);
            break;

}

}

rewind(infile2);
}


fclose(infile1);
fclose(infile2);
fclose(infile3);

}
```

La idea del programa es que me lea los nombres del primer archivo, se fije si existe en el segundo archivo, y copie los datos de este en un tercer archivo.
Ahora bien, esto lo hace perfectamente, pero cuando termina de ejecutarse en la terminal me aparece **"Violación de segmento (`core' generado)"**, y no entiendo por qué.

Comment: ¿Has probado a depurarlo a ver en qué punto está fallando? Con la información que nos das no queda muy claro dónde puede estar el problema

Comment: Por ejemplo estaría bien conocer la longitud máxima de cada campo en los ficheros de lectura

Comment: Cuando lees de `infile2` siempre lees de 3 en 3 palabras (puesto que `scanf("%s")` se detiene ante el primer espacio, tabulador o retorno de carro). Si el número de palabras en `infile2` no es múltiplo de 3, la última lectura te devolverá un `EOF` y dejará alguna de las variables (`len_sec` o `sec_dom`) sin inicializar. Aún si el número de palabras es múltiplo de 3, la última lectura del fichero devolverá `EOF` y dejará los tres arrays sin inicializar. Aunque en principio no veo que eso vaya a genera un segfault (mantendrían el valor de la última lectura), por ahi pueden venir los problemas.